# How to download XML web page with Wget

Tags: unix, wget

I want to download an XML from the [web](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=%28Alum%29%20AND%20Adjuvant&retmax=10) using Unix `wget`.
In principle to simple get it and save it into a file.

This is the command I use:

```
wget http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=Alum+AND+Adjuvant&retmax=100 --output-document=test.xml
```

But if failed to download it. What's the right way to go?

Comment: Perhaps you should use some quoting to avoid having the shell interpret the meta characters (like `&` and `?`).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You must quote the url like

```
 wget "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=Alum+AND+Adjuvant&retmax=100" --output-document=test.xml
```

since the url contains meta characters that influence the processing of the line.

Answer (score 6):

if the `--output-document` does not work, you can use the `-O`

```
wget -O test.xml
    "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=Alum+AND+Adjuvant&retmax=100"
```

Comment: -o worked for me and my OS is windows 10. Kudos

Answer (score 0):

```
 wget --output-document=test.xml "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=Alum+AND+Adjuvant&retmax=100"
```

Comment: Please provide information on what you are doing and why, instead of pasting only code.